# Remove duplicated rows based on a Series of lists in which item order doesn't matter

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a lot of columns. But one column has values/lists that look like this:

```
df =

   val1
   ---------------
0  ["hej", "hello"]
1  ["mus", "mouse"]
2  ["hest", "horse"]
3  ["hello", "hej"]
4  ["mouse", "mus"]
```

If I just do:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["val1"], keep="first")
```

Nothing will get dropped in this case. However, in my case `["hej", "hello"]` is the same as `["hello", "hej"]` and `["mus", "mouse"]` is the same as `["mouse", "mus"]`. So in this case it should just keep `["hej", "hello"]` and `["mus", "mouse"]`, ending up with a data frame with the rows:

```
df_final =

   val1
   ---------------
0  ["hej", "hello"]
1  ["mus", "mouse"]
2  ["hest", "horse"]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert to [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) and use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df_final = df[~df['val1'].apply(frozenset).duplicated()]
```

Or, if there are duplicated values and the number matters, use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
df_final = df[~df['val1'].apply(Counter).duplicated()]
```

Output:

```
            val1
0   [hej, hello]
1   [mus, mouse]
2  [hest, horse]
```

Difference of the two approaches:

```
# input
                val1
0       [hej, hello]
1       [mus, mouse]
2      [hest, horse]
3       [hello, hej]
4       [mouse, mus]
5  [mouse, mus, mus]   # two rows with duplicated items
6  [mus, mouse, mus]   #

# output with frozenset
            val1
0   [hej, hello]
1   [mus, mouse]
2  [hest, horse]

# output with Counter
                val1
0       [hej, hello]
1       [mus, mouse]
2      [hest, horse]
5  [mouse, mus, mus]  # this one has 2 "mus"
```